# why request.GET.get() returns 'None' and value of html element is not visible in URL

Tags: python, django, get

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>HELLO</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/removepunc", method="get">
        <input type="text",name='text' value="Hello,Django" />
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
    return render(request,'index.html')

def removepunc(request):
    print("Text is :"+request.GET.get('text','default'))
    return HttpResponse("Hello")
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.index,name='index'),
    path('removepunc',views.removepunc,name='rempunc')

]
```

[This is first screen after run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0v6V.png)

[When I click on submit in Url it did not show "hello django"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9WPU.png)

[Also in terminal it print default not "hello django"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPeRj.png)

Comment: There is a comma in your `<input>` box, and you did not wrap it in double quotes (`"..."`).

Answer (score 1):

There is a comma in your `<input>` box between `"text"` and `name`.

The `<input>` tag should thus look like:

```
<input type="text" name="text" value="Hello,Django" />
```

not:

```
<input type="text",name='text' value="Hello,Django" />
```

Comment: Thank You so much such a small mistake it was...Thank you